# Managing thread schedulers when concat observables

Tags: android, rx-java

I have a code like this:

```
service.getUserById(10)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .concatMap(getFullUserFromDto())
    .subscribe(doSomehingWithUser());

 private Func1<UserDto, Observable<User>> getFullUserFromDto() {
     return new Func1<UserDto, Observable<User>>() {
         @Override
         public Observable<User> call(final UserDto dto) {
             return dao.getUserById(dto.getUserId());
         }
     };
 }
```

and in my DAO, I have:

```
 public Observable<User> getUserById(final Long id) {
        return api.getUserById(id).map(//more things...
 }
```

Note there are two levels of "concatenation": `service` -> `dao` -> `api`. Method `api.getUserById(id)` make a network call.

I'm getting `NetworkOnMainThreadException` error. Why? I'm using and `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` operators, but it seems that it is not applied to the "final" built Observable.

If I use this operators in the API call, in the DAO, it works:

```
return api.getUserById(id)
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
     .map(//more things...
```

Is there a way to use just once in the "root" Observable?

Comment: Your error is in `api.getUserById(id)` and you fix it by `api.getUserById(id).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`, which means **you should include your implementation of `api.getUserById()`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `concatMap` subscribes on Observables. What thread is used to perform this operation? Well, the thread that called `onNext` for the `concatMat`, given that it doesn't change threads/schedulers. So, one simple transposition should help with this:

```
service.getUserById(10)
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
  .concatMap(getFullUserFromDto())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(doSomehingWithUser());
```

I'd also suggest to use Schedulers.io(), as it will re-use threads.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: use `observeOn` before chained operations to controll on which schedulers they are executed:

```
service.getUserById(10)
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
  .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .concatMap(getFullUserFromDto())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(doSomehingWithUser());
```

In the example above, `.concatMap` will be executed in `Schedulers.io()`

More details can be found here: 
http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.com/2016/02/rxjava-understanding-observeon-and.html

Comment: Don't wanna be Captain Obvious, but because you're doing network operations on main thread, in the `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`. I think you can debug your code by printing out the current thread `Thread.currentThread()`, that should give more insight on what's going on